# R adding a df with less rows to an existing data frame and show NA

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame, say df1, that looks something like this:

```
    ID     
1   ABC
2   ABD
3   ABE
4   ABF
5   ABG
.
.
```

and I want to join a data frame to df1 that has less rows than df1, like this one:

```
    ID     Value1    Value 2
1   ABC      5         6
2   ABD      1         2
3   ABG      4         4
.
.
```

so that the final product looks like this:

```
    ID     Value1    Value 2
1   ABC      5         6
2   ABD      1         2
3   ABE      NA        NA
4   ABF      NA        NA 
5   ABG      4         4
.
.
```

How can I do about doing this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into the `merge` function.  Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge unequal dataframes and replace missing rows with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965698/merge-unequal-dataframes-and-replace-missing-rows-with-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Data

```
df1 = data.frame(ID =  c("ABC", "ABD", "ABE", "ABF", "ABG"))
df2 = data.frame(ID =  c("ABC", "ABD", "ABG"), Value1 = c(5, 4, 1), Value2 = c(6, 2, 4))
```

## Solution

```
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)

#   ID Value1 Value2
#1 ABC      5      6
#2 ABD      4      2
#3 ABE     NA     NA
#4 ABF     NA     NA
#5 ABG      1      4
```

## Explanation

Reading `?merge`, we see that the logical argument `all.x` does exactly what you wanted:

> all.x
>
> logical; if TRUE, then extra rows will be added to the output, one for
>   each row in x that has no matching row in y. These rows will have NAs
>   in those columns that are usually filled with values from y. The
>   default is FALSE, so that only rows with data from both x and y are
>   included in the output.

Comment: Thanks! However, there's an error: cannot allocate vector of size 925.2 Mb, I'm assuming because my df is so large (10,000+ entries). Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @AlexJohanssen Your data is too big to be fit into memory, you have to sort that first. 10k entries isn't that big though.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can sort this out? It's still not completing its task after I run gc().

Comment: @AlexJohanssen I have no way to know why it's happening to you. I suggest you search this problem here on SO, and if no one asked it yet, ask it yourself.

Comment: Good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge(df1,df2,by = "ID", all = TRUE)`