# Combine Dataframe based on value in row in R

Tags: r, merge

I have 5 dataframes each with a different number of rows. I need to merge them all together based on values in col1 of each dataframe. Observe

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
   col1    col2
    A        5
    B        3
    C        6
    E        7", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text="
   col1    col2
    A        5
    B        6
    C       7
    M       8
    Z       9", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But I need it to produce:

```
   newdf
     col1    col2(#from df1)   col3(#from df2)
      A          5                  5
      B          3                  6
      C          6                  7  
      E          7                  0
      M          0                  8
      Z          0                  9
```

I have tried to merge a few at a time `by='col1'` but to no luck. Any tips?

What I have tried:

```
posidf<-merge(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,all.x=TRUE)
#wont execute
posidf<-merge(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,by="col1",all.x=TRUE)
#wont execute
posidf<-merge(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,by="col1")
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

Comment: What exactly did your merge command look like? What does "no avail" mean exactly? Did you get an error message? Did you get output other than what you expected? Was the problem missing rows? Did you try setting the `all=` parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965698/merge-unequal-dataframes-and-replace-missing-rows-with-0

Comment: @MrFlick edited. I tried the 'all-' as well. No Avail means it didn't work out.

Comment: `merge()` only takes two data.frames. You cannot pass in an arbitrary number of them? Check out the `?merge` help page. You would have to repeatedly call something like `merge(merge(merge(a,b), c, d)` . Did you try it with just two data frames like the example you actually included in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like this example:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "col1", all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
```

**Edit:**

```
col1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'E')
col2 <- c(5, 3, 6 ,7)
df1 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

col1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'Z')
col2 <- c(5, 6, 7 ,8, 9)
df2 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

col1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
col2 <- c(10, 29, 7)
df3 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

col1 <- c('A', 'S', 'T')
col2 <- c(7 ,8, 9)
df4 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

col1 <- c('B', 'C')
col2 <- c(7 ,8)
df5 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

frame_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
frame_names <- list('df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5')
counter <- 0

df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 File=character(), 
                 User=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("col1","col2")

for (d in frame_list) {
  counter <- counter + 1
  colnames(d) <- c("col1", paste0('col2_',frame_names[counter]))
  df <- merge(df, d, by = "col1", all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
}

df$col2 <- NULL
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Comment: Check out the updated question. The problem appears to be that the OP is trying to merge 5 data.frames, not just 2. This doesn't seem to address that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your merge looks like this and your example is representative of your data, there are no issues.

```
newdf <- merge(x = df1, y = df2,'col1')

##  col1 col2.x col2.y
##1    A      5      5
##2    B      3      6
##3    C      6      7
```

If this is not the output you expect, you may want to look into the different types of merging: **inner join** (above), **outer join**, **left outer**, and **right outer**.

**Outer join**

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'col1', all = TRUE)

##  col1 col2.x col2.y
##1    A      5      5
##2    B      3      6
##3    C      6      7
##4    E      7     NA
##5    M     NA      8
##6    Z     NA      9
```

**Left outer**

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'col1', all.x = TRUE)

##  col1 col2.x col2.y
##1    A      5      5
##2    B      3      6
##3    C      6      7
##4    E      7     NA
```

**Right outer**

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = 'col1', all.y = TRUE)

##  col1 col2.x col2.y
##1    A      5      5
##2    B      3      6
##3    C      6      7
##4    M     NA      8
##5    Z     NA      9
```

Comment: Check out the updated question. The problem appears to be that the OP is trying to merge 5 data.frames, not just 2. This doesn't seem to address that problem.

Comment: Thanks. Assumed the example was accurate to the problem. I'll edit a new response

Comment: I agree the example was misleading. But I also think the duplicate suggested by  @zx8754 takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you would like is a full_join. Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "E"),
  col2 = c(5, 3, 6, 7)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "M", "Z"),
  col2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
)


df_merged <- full_join(x = df1, y = df2, by = "col1")
```

If you want a `0` instead of a `NA`, replace them with

`df_merged[is.na(df_merged)] <- 0`

```
  col1 col2.x col2.y
1    A      5      5
2    B      3      6
3    C      6      7
4    E      7      0
5    M      0      8
6    Z      0      9
```

**Edit for multiple data frames**

Store them in a list and use `reduce` with the respective join, here `full_join`

```
set.seed(123)
df_list <- replicate(5, data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[sample(1:26, 5)], col2 = sample(1:9, 5)), simplify = F)
reduce(df_list, full_join, by = "col1")

   col1 col2.x col2.y col2.x.x col2.y.y col2
1     E      9     NA       NA        1    4
2     F      5     NA       NA       NA   NA
3     N      2     NA       NA        8   NA
4     X      7      4       NA       NA    6
5     P      8     NA       NA        5   NA
6     D     NA      8       NA       NA   NA
7     Q     NA      5       NA       NA   NA
8     J     NA      1       NA       NA   NA
9     U     NA      2       NA        9    8
10    V     NA     NA        1       NA   NA
11    M     NA     NA        7       NA   NA
12    B     NA     NA        8       NA   NA
13    H     NA     NA        9       NA   NA
14    I     NA     NA        4       NA   NA
15    K     NA     NA       NA        6   NA
16    W     NA     NA       NA       NA    9
17    O     NA     NA       NA       NA    3
```

But as @zx8754 suggested in the comment: duplicate from here [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: Check out the updated question. The problem appears to be that the OP is trying to merge 5 data.frames, not just 2. This doesn't seem to address that problem.

Comment: I see, updated the response which copies from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list as already @zx8754 suggested